# How to fix 'Could not parse for environment production' error?

Tags: puppet

Here is my little puppet snippet: when i execute this snippet i got the following error:

> err: Could not parse for environment production: Could not match   at /home/test.pp:8

```
$vendor = generate("/usr/bin/lsscsi")

if defined($vendor) {
    if $vendor =~ /LSI/{
        $d_multipath = [{
            vendor => 'LSI',
            product => 'INF-01-00',
            path_checker => 'rdac',
            path_selector => 'round-robin 0',
       }]
    }
}
else {
    notify {'faield-lsscsi':
        message  => "ERROR: failed to execute lsscsi to get the scsi vendor type",
        loglevel => critical,
    }
}
```

Could some one please help in pointing out?

Comment: The error is not related the code you pasted, and maybe you can try to run `puppet apply --environment=production`

Comment: https://docs.puppetlabs.com/learning/manifests.html#syntax-hints

Comment: I check the code with `puppet parser validate test.pp`, no error is reported. Do you paste all codes here?

Comment: Ya i got that error while running validate. and i am not able to install puppet-lint.

Comment: I copy/paste the code on my environment and run with validate, didn't get any errors. Are there any hide characters in the pp file?

Comment: can you remove `[` and `]` on line 5 and 10, then try again?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Regarding error `Could not parse for environment production`, you can check url https://docs.puppetlabs.com/learning/manifests.html#syntax-hints

```
Syntax Hints

Watch out for these common errors:

Don’t forget commas and colons! Forgetting them causes errors like Could not parse for environment production: Syntax error at 'mode'; expected '}' at /root/manifests/1.file.pp:6 on node learn.localdomain.

Capitalization matters! The resource type and the attribute names should always be lowercase.
The values used for titles and attribute values will usually be strings, which you should usually quote. Read more about Puppet’s data types here.

There are two kinds of quotes in Puppet: single (') and double ("). The main difference is that double quotes let you interpolate $variables, which we cover in another lesson.

Attribute names (like path, ensure, etc.) are special keywords, not strings. They shouldn’t be quoted.

Also, note that Puppet lets you use whatever whitespace makes your manifests more readable. We suggest visually lining up the => arrows, because it makes it easier to understand a manifest at a glance. (The Vim plugins on the Learning Puppet VM will do this automatically as you type.)
```

For troubleshooting and validate manifest (*.pp) file, you can run :

```
puppet parser validate test.pp
```

or you can install `puppet-lint` (http://puppet-lint.com/) for help as well.

Third, find out if there are any hidden characters to make the trouble.

Answer (score 2):

The error:

> Error: Could not parse for environment production

is always followed by another error, for example:

- > Syntax error at 'x': expected 'x' at manifest.pp:123

  Which could indicate a missing comma.
- > Could not match at manifest.pp:123

  which could indicate a missing bracket.

So you should check the file at the specific line where the error is reported to see if the previous line has missing any commas or brackets (which is the most common mistake for that kind of error).

Answer (score 1):

This Error also appears when the host  has a duplicate entry in nodes.pp file.
In case there are multiple host in the file, please make sure there is single entry for a host.

Answer (score 0):

Also check for missing quotation marks immediately before the point at which Puppet reports the error.